# ERROR 1045 (28000) MYSQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, back-end

Estou começando com o **back-end** e estou com dificuldade ao instalar o ***mysql***, depois de instalar e fazer todos procedimentos ao tentar rodar o ***mysql*** aparece o seguinte erro (vale ressaltar que rodo com o sudo)...

primeiro digito no terminal

```
$ sudo mysql
```

e retorna o seguinte erro:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using 
password: NO)
```

Alguém pode me explicar detalhadamente, como faço para instalar corretamente, pois já assisti e fiz a leitura de muito conteúdo mas sempre da o mesmo erro. Obrigado

Comment: Isso não é erro na instalação, o comando `mysql` está sem parametros ai no seu "teste", logo ele não está acessando nada, ou entendi errado.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento como eu faço para passar os parametros, poderia me ajudar?

Comment: @GustavoDazzle, quando você instalou o MySQL configurou alguma senha?

Comment: @LuizFelipe não, apenas dei o comando install msql-server e esperei instalar.

Comment: Isso é um problema de suporte, não de programação. Basicamente você está tentando usar credenciais inválidas, o erro indica que você não tentou senha nenhuma. É questão de ler o manual do cliente da linha de comando. Adicionalmente, se pesquisar pelo erro, vai ver algumas postagens tratando do assunto (inclusive indicando como alterar a senha).

Comment: Que comandos? O que deseja fazer com o comando mysql? Isso ai não tem nada haver com o node.js, o node.js tem lib para mysql e não tem nada haver com o comando de linha.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você provavelmente não está passando as credenciais de "login" corretas, isto é, o nome de usuário e a senha.

O usuário padrão é o `root`. Então você pode tentar:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

A flag `-u` determina o usuário que eu quero me conectar. E a flag `-p` vai abrir um prompt para que eu digite a senha assim que eu executar o comando. Se você não tiver configurado nenhuma senha, ela pode ser vazia (só aperte <kbd>Enter</kbd>) ou simplesmente `root`).

Para saber todas as flags do `mysql`, execute `mysql --help`.

Comment: Certo, explicou muito bem... eu consegui entender o comando, obrigado por isso. Mas, eu já tinha visto isso (só não tinha entendido). Tem como eu reconfigurar essa senha de root? pq não está funcionando

Comment: Veja se a [documentação do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html) te ajuda.